# Uploadcare uploading images input not been shown with Meteor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, uploadcare

I'm using uploadcare to upload image but I'm unable to see the button to upload.

I have set my public key in the main.html inside script tags and also install via npm install.

This is the code I have inside my form, what am I missing? I'm new to uploadcare so I'm not quite sure what other fields it takes or how to use them, I know that "role" is required.

```
<input type="hidden" role="uploadcare-uploader" name="my_file" />
```

Note; I'm using meteor and react to build my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's hard to see what went wrong with your code judging by a single line of code, but here is a [demo](https://github.com/uploadcare/meteor-react-uploadcare-demo) I put together for using Uploadcare widget with Meteor + ReactJS combination.

For Meteor + Blaze demo please visit [this](https://github.com/uploadcare/meteor-uploadcare-widget-demo) page.